# Why does a particle fall in a straight line?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

In Lagrangian Mechanics we choose the path of least action.

Given a uniform gravitational field, and a particle of finite mass; and fixing two points the start & end-point we consider all paths connecting the two points and minimise the action. This turns out to be a Brachistone, as first shown by Bernouilli.

When we fix the end-point vertically below; the Brachistone is in fact astraight-line.

But is there a principle in Lagrangian Mechanics that allows me to choose the point vertically below?

Of course, we know from Newtons Mechanics that this must be the case. But how do we determine that end-point entirely within Lagrangian Mechanics?

Answer (score 1):

The Euler Lagrange equations just give the differential equations that determine the motion of the object. The end points are boundary conditions for the differential equation. The differential equation which the brachistochrone curve satisfies will have its constants fixed so that it reduces to a line when you give it the boundary conditions of the object starting and ending in one vertical position.

So, if you will, the end points are part of the problem statement, they are not determined by the Euler-Lagrange equations.